# JRE crashes frequently. I am using RXTX with Java (1.6) for serialcomm in Linux. Exception

Tags: java, linux, rxtx

```
An unexpected error has been detected by Java Runtime Environment:

SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0xb7e50e81, pid=18299, tid=2909465488

 Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (10.0-b22 mixed mode linux-x86)
 Problematic frame:
 C  [libc.so.6+0x68e81]

 An error report file with more information is saved as:
 /home/user/hs_err_pid18299.log

 If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
  http://java.sun.com/webapps/bugreport/crash.jsp
 The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
 See problematic frame for where to report the bug.

Experimental:  JNI_OnLoad called.
```

Comment: What version of RXTX are you using?

Comment: That appears to be Java 6 update 6 which is about four years old.  If you suspect a bug in the JVM, I suggest trying a more recent version like Java 6 update 35.

Comment: @Peter - not unreasonable. However RXTX has a native component too

Comment: @BrianAgnew I suspect its more likely to be a bug in the RXTX library. ;)

Answer (score 1):

I would try to get more info by [diagnosing what's going on using the hs_err file](http://weblogs.java.net/blog/kohsuke/archive/2009/02/crash_course_on.html).